# Ibm Db2 Jdbc Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I  I am getting below error  Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:794)  Also the output is  Start time: 2024-03-28T12:59:39.726 Connection created for Database1: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b@5e1218b4 There were 260 records. com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10120][10898][4.25.13] Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null  Actually i am connecting to database but the above has been dispalyed.  Please help in reolving the error

```
    try {
        // Create Statement Object
        con = dbConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        // Execute the SQL Query. Store results in ResultSet
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        int rowCount = 0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            rowCount++;
        }
        System.out.println("There were " + rowCount + " records.");
        

        

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        
        

        while (rs.next()) {
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= columnCount) {
                row.add(rs.getString(i++));
            }

            result.add(row);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null!= con)
            con.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: you think after completing while (rs.next()) -> rs will still have a next?

Comment: I am not thinking what should i do code changes so that it will not display that error.

Comment: there are TWO while loops checking the same condition

Comment: that is not a problem. THis is the error [jcc][t4][10120][10898][4.25.13] Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:794)

Comment: After the first loop the ResulSet-cursor is positioned after the last result-record. so what would you expect the following `next()` to return?

Comment: Piet where u think I should do the changes in the code

Comment: Read up on the `beforeFirst()` method, then think about where to place it...

Comment: can u send me the code here

Comment: After removing the first while statement this is the error

Comment: Invalid parameter 9: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:810)

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine if you just remove the rowCount++; loop